# How to get multiple titles using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Suppose my text is

```html
dl class="dl-horizontal">
 <dt title="Name">
  Name
 </dt>
 <dd>
  Phillips
 </dd>
 <dt title="Birth date">
  Birth date
 </dt>
 <dd>
  17/09/1990
 </dd>
 <dt title="Location">
  Location
 </dt>
 <dd>
  Northland
 </dd>
</dl>
```

I need to extract all the titles as follows

```
Name - Phillips
Birth Date - 17/09/1990
Location - Northland
```

What I am trying to do is

```py
  list=soup.find_all('title')
```

But I get an empty *list* whereas i expected to get the list of titles ['Name', 'Birth Date', 'Location'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
for a,b in zip(soup.select('dl dt'),soup.select('dl dd')):
    print(a.attrs['title'],b.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Name Phillips
Birth date 17/09/1990
Location Northland
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for a tag name with specific attributes

You can either specify the attribute values explicitly, like so

```
soup.find_all('dt', {'title': ['Name', 'Birth date', 'Location']})
```

or look for any `dt` tag with the attribute `title`

```
soup.find_all('dt', {'title': True})
```

or

```
soup.find_all(title=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the element need to use the tag, after that you will need to get the next element with the value.

Following give you an example

```
list = soup.find_all('dt')

dict_to_format = []
for dt_element in list:
    if dt_element.attrs.get('title'):
        target_text = dt_element.find_next_sibling("dd").text.replace("\n", "").strip()
        dict_to_format.append((dt_element.attrs.get('title'), target_text))

print(dict(dict_to_format))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think class and ID are a better solution

Comment: There are no class or ID  attributes in this example